# Need to create exponential data(number) in single cell in apache poi without using paragraph.break

Tags: apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I am constructing a row  with 8 columns and 
Need to create exponential data(number) in single cell in apache poi WORD without using paragraph.break .

[image: second column exponential data without pagebreak]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content `(2)` shall be superscript, then there are two possibilities using `Microsoft Word`. Either really superscript align or set the text position away from the text base line. For both the `(2)` must be in it's own text run.

Superscript alignment can be achieved using [XWPFRun.setSubscript](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#setSubscript-org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.VerticalAlign-) having [VerticalAlign](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/VerticalAlign.html)`.SUPERSCRIPT`.

Text position can be set using [XWPFRun.setTextPosition](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#setTextPosition-int-) where `int val` is of measurement unit half pt.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordSuperScript {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph;
  XWPFRun run;

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("6  ");
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("(2)");
  run.setSubscript(VerticalAlign.SUPERSCRIPT); // superscript (2)

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("6  ");
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("(2)");
  run.setTextPosition(11); // (2) position = baseline + 11 half pt ~ 5.5 pt

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("word.docx"); 
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("6  ");
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("(2)");
  run.setSubscript(VerticalAlign.SUPERSCRIPT); // superscript (2) - this is required for the requirement